# Working instructions for Azure AKS + Azure Application Gateway?

Tags: azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

Does anyone have working instructions for using AKS + Azure Application gateway for ingress? The instructions from Microsoft don't work (Helm issues among others)

This should be a one click in portal or a single az ask xxx line to go and inject it and make it work so that all you have to do is add an ingress to your scripts, but it's phenomenally complex and the docs are already out of date.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, I also feel your pain and needs. If you weren't aware yet, the AKS team is looking at making the AppGW ingress-controller a managed solution within AKS

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1441

Regarding what can be done at this time, I would recommend following the GreenField deployment solution: (maybe that's the one you have been following ?)

https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/setup/install-new.md

It isn't a simple task with a single command line indeed, but it had proven to work

If you would like to share exactly your issue and the step number you are having issues with, I would be happy to help.

Comment: I've tried both the greenfield and brownfield. Installing the helm-config.yaml after making updates errors because it's from helm 2 not 3 which is installed on Azure Cloud CLI

Comment: Turns out that Application Gateway also doesn't support gRPC...